# Mixed schema datatype JSON to PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I need to transform a list of JSONs into pySpark DataFrames. The JSON all have the same Schema. The problem is that the **value-entries** of the dicts in the JSON have *different data types*.

Example: The field `complex` is an Array of Dicts, the Dicts has four keys but of different types (Integer, String, Float and a nested Dict). See below for an example JSON.

If I use `df = spark.createDataFrame(json_list)` to create my DataFrame from the jsons, pyspark "deletes" some of the data as he cannot infer the Schema correctly. PySpark decides
that the Schema of the `complex`-field should be: `StructType("complex", ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), LongType())))` **which leads to the non-LongType values being nulled.**

I tried to supply a schema, but since I need to set a *specific* (?) DataType for the value fields of the nested MapType - which is not uniform, but varies...

```
myschema = StructType([
                             StructField("Id", StringType(), True),
                             StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                             StructField("sentTimestamp", LongType(), True),
                             StructType("complex", ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
                             ])
```

The `MapType(StringType(), StringType())))` means some value-fields in the dict are being nulled as it cannot be mapped.

It seems that PySpark can only handle dicts if all data types of the values are the same.

How can I convert the JSON to a pyspark DataFrame without loosing data?

```
[{
    "Id": "2345123",
    "name": "something",        
    "sentTimestamp": 1646732402,
    "complex":
    [
        {
            "key1": 1,
            "key2": "(1)",
            "key3": 0.5,
            "key4":
            {
                "innerkey1": "random",
                "innerkey2": 5.4,
                "innerkey3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": 2,
            "key2": "(2)",
            "key3": 0.5,
            "key4":
            {
                "innerkey1": "left",
                "innerkey2": 7.8,
                "innerkey3": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the schema of the `complex` column as an array of struct.

```
myschema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("Id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("sentTimestamp", LongType(), True),
        StructField(
            "complex",
            ArrayType(StructType(
                [
                    StructField("key1", LongType(), True),
                    StructField("key2", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("key3", StringType(), True),
                    StructField(
                        "key4",
                        StructType(
                            [
                                StructField("innerkey1", StringType(), True),
                                StructField("innerkey2", StringType(), True),
                                StructField("innerkey3", IntegerType(), True),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                ]
            ))
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: So simple, so elegant. Amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to pass a schema or want spark to detect schema from 3.0+ you can write json into a table

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT
'{
    "Id": "2345123",
    "name": "something",        
    "sentTimestamp": 1646732402,
    "complex":
    [
        {
            "key1": 1,
            "key2": "(1)",
            "key3": 0.5,
            "key4":
            {
                "innerkey1": "random",
                "innerkey2": 5.4,
                "innerkey3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": 2,
            "key2": "(2)",
            "key3": 0.5,
            "key4":
            {
                "innerkey1": "left",
                "innerkey2": 7.8,
                "innerkey3": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}'as original
```

Convert the table into a dataframe

```
df1 =spark.sql('select * from newtable')
```

`rdd` the single column in the table

```
rdd=df1.select(col("original").alias("jsoncol")).rdd.map(lambda x: x.jsoncol)
```

Leverage `.read` to read the `rdd` schema and set is avariable

```
newschema=spark.read.json(rdd).schema
```

Assign schema to column using select

```
df3=df1.select("*",from_json("original", newschema).alias("transrequest"))

df3.select('transrequest.*').show(truncate=False)

+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|Id     |complex                                                         |name     |sentTimestamp|
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|2345123|[{1, (1), 0.5, {random, 5.4, 1}}, {2, (2), 0.5, {left, 7.8, 1}}]|something|1646732402   |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

schema

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- complex: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key3: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- innerkey1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- innerkey2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- innerkey3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sentTimestamp: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @过过招 's answer, below is the approach I would personally use since it involves lesser code while defining the `dataframe` schema.

**Input JSON**

```
jsonstr = """[{
    "Id": "2345123",
    "name": "something",        
    "sentTimestamp": 1646732402,
    "complex":
    [
        {
            "key1": 1,
            "key2": "(1)",
            "key3": 0.5,
            "key4":
            {
                "innerkey1": "random",
                "innerkey2": 5.4,
                "innerkey3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": 2,
            "key2": "(2)",
            "key3": 0.5,
            "key4":
            {
                "innerkey1": "left",
                "innerkey2": 7.8,
                "innerkey3": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}]"""
```

Converting this to a `RDD` -

```
import json

rdd = sc.parallelize(json.loads(jsonstr))
```

Creating the `dataframe` -

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd, 'Id string, name string, sentTimestamp long, complex array<struct<key1:int, key2:string, key3:float, key4:struct<innerkey1:string,innerkey2:float,innerkey3:int>>>')
df.show(truncate=False)

#Output Data
+-------+---------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Id     |name     |sentTimestamp|complex                                                         |
+-------+---------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|2345123|something|1646732402   |[{1, (1), 0.5, {random, 5.4, 1}}, {2, (2), 0.5, {left, 7.8, 1}}]|
+-------+---------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+

#Output Schema
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sentTimestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- complex: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key3: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- innerkey1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- innerkey2: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- innerkey3: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: You will have to define the Schema in the String though which is a lot more errorprone (and harder to debug) than defining the Schema outright with `StructType/StructField` classes.

Comment: @Cribber Depends on personal preference and ease of understanding.